# CRITICAL ERROR: Magic number mismatch - Insight, Bitcore

Tags: bitcore

Edit: Apparently I need rep here to post links, so I apologize for the lack of urls.

I am trying to adapt a bitpay's insight blockchain explorer and API to an alt coin(https://github.com/potcoin/Potcoin) using the PoSV algo.  The coin itself uses an older version of the Reddcoin PoSV algo.  I've tried to follow Reddcoin's version of the block explorer/api/etc) and have gone as far as cloning it to try to make this work.

networks.js:

```
exports.livenet = {
  name: 'livenet',
  magic: hex('fbc0b6db'),
  addressVersion: 55, // 37
  privKeyVersion: 189,
  P2SHVersion: 5,
  hkeyPublicVersion: 0x0488b21e,
  hkeyPrivateVersion: 0x0488ade4,
  genesisBlock: {
    hash: hex('ec3513ee046dcd52dd41975fcfab4f878f91890a4d17c07a1d7d9c2acbb036de'),
    merkle_root: hex('3de5af055300a913c07e178efc107c9184dddcbc9d888aae7eea6ee00686a0d5'),
    height: 0,
    nonce: 471993,
    version: 1,
    prev_hash: buffertools.fill(new Buffer(32), 0),
    timestamp: 1389688315,
    bits: 3165306666666630
  },
  dnsSeeds: [
    'seedz.potcoin.info'
  ],
  defaultClientPort: 45444,
  lastPoWBlock: 974999
};
```

The chain will sync until ~27% without any issue and then gives this error:

```
Error: CRITICAL ERROR: Magic number mismatch: 00000014!=fbc0b6db
```

I'm at a complete loss as to why this is happening.  This is at block `458581`.  I have a discussion open with a Reddcoin developer as well and can be found here(https://github.com/reddcoin-project/reddcore/issues/3).  Any help or a point in how to debug or fix this is much appreciated.